# In Swift, why do subclass designated initializers follow this order?

Tags: swift, inheritance, initialization

I'm trying to understand how the compiler works around this.

I've read that `subclass` designated initializers must:

1. First initialize all properties of the `subclass`.
2. Then call `super.init()`.

I don't understand why the `subclass` must initialise first and the initialise the `superclass`. How is this possible if the `superclass` doesn't exist yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID215 under "Two-Phase Initialization", it is explained extensively

The main reason is safety.  Each property must first assign a value -- and then only when the entire hierarchy has done that, can you start reading values.

The reason super.init() comes after subclass property initialization is so that super.init() can call a method that might be overridden in your class.  When it does that, we know that you have already given your properties an initial value.